# SQL subquery: if condition is true take take all rows for this "group" if it's false then take non

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data of the following format as a result of a first query.
Now i need to add second query with a condition, which is hard for me and maybe someone can help me out with this one.

**The condition is:**

If the **type** for the **customers** row with the highest **product_id** is **Y**, then take all rows for given customer, if it is **X** then take non.

So I need to somehow select for each customer row with highest product_id, check if in that row type is Y, and then regarding on the result take all or non of the given customer data.

```
index    customer    product_id    type
-----------------------------------------
1           1          51           X      
2           1          42           Y      
3           1          11           X      
            
4           2          4            Y      
5           2          2            Y      
            
6           3          41           Y      
7           3          22           Y      
8           3          21           X      
9           3          20           X      

10          4          16           X
11          4          15           Y
12          4          14           Y
13          4          13           Y
14          4          12           Y
```

So in the example above I'd like to return rows: 4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT [index], [customer], [product_id], [type]
FROM (
  SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE([type]) OVER (PARTITION BY [customer] ORDER BY [product_id] DESC) [value]
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE [value] = 'Y'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d278a1bca6d38e99efde981974d702ec).
Results:

```
> index | customer | product_id | type
> ----: | -------: | ---------: | :---
>     4 |        2 |          4 | Y   
>     5 |        2 |          2 | Y   
>     6 |        3 |         41 | Y   
>     7 |        3 |         22 | Y   
>     8 |        3 |         21 | X   
>     9 |        3 |         20 | X
```

Comment: Let me give you the last upvote you need to reach 100k... Congratulations for this achievement!

Comment: @GMB thanks, but from what I've seen there has been a serial upvoting of +4 which will be reversed by the system...